# jQuery: Loop through elements and number the children

Tags: jquery, loops, numbers

I want to number each span element containing the list, always beginning from 1. But now its continuous:

http://jsfiddle.net/QaB76/125/

the markup

```
<li>
  <span class="1"><span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="2"><span>
  <span class="3"><span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="5"><span>
  <span class="6"><span>
</li>
```

but i want it to be:

```
<li>
  <span class="1"><span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="1"><span>
  <span class="2"><span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="1"><span>
  <span class="2"><span>
  <span class="3"><span>
</li>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use separate `each()` iterations for the `li` and `span` elements

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").each(function (i) {
        $(this).find("span").each(function (i) {
            $(this).attr('class', (i + 1));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li> <span>test</span>

    </li>
    <li> <span>test</span><span>test</span>

    </li>
    <li> <span>test</span><span>test</span><span>test</span>

    </li>
</ul>
```